# How to fixed the nav menu on top for rest of the page except home(Front Page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This is my link http://developermobulous.com I have fixed my nav menu at the bottom but it goes on top when page scrolls for the Front Page(Home) but I want for the rest of pages, Menu fixed on the top so can you give some hands on script or the way how can I achieve this.

your answer will really appreciating

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(is_singular ()) { ?>
        /* Wrap everything between: <header id="masthead"> until </header>*/
<?php } ?>
```

**Put this code above** `<header id="masthead"...>`

```
<?php if(is_singular ()) { ?>
```

**and this code below** `</header><!-- #masthead-two -->`

```
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Well I just realized that your menu has JS animation that changes from header_bottom to header_top, that way is more complicated to make that happen because you don't have a cut edge to start wrap because it's gonna affect the header_bottom as well. I thought it was 2 different menus

Comment: exactly I am using animation as this is our requirement. Could we still implement your solution or can you give me other way

Comment: Well my suggestion is to duplicate your menu but give different names, that way you can display 1 menu on the front page, and the animated one on all other pages. Once you created another header_bottom with no animation, wrap it inside of: `<?php if(is_home ()) { ?>` your new menu code goes here `<?php } ?>` then you'll be able to do that on the answer I gave you.
I can't help you more than this because there's a bunch of code that I need to go through, and the best way would be by doing it myself directly if I had an admin account on your website. I'm with tied hands.